# Confusion about the composition of the `cmd` parameter used in Deno.run()

Tags: deno

I tried to use Deno as a replacement for shell script, but got stuck.

I attempted to use Deno/Typescript to carry out the equivalent job as this:

```sh
docker run \
  -d \
  -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  --name pg \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456 \
  --rm \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  postgres
```

ts code looks like this:

```
function runCmd(s: string[]): Deno.Process {
    return Deno.run({ cmd: s, stdout: "piped", stderr: "piped" })
}

function runPg() {
    const cmd = [
        "docker", 
        `run -d -v ${VOLUME}:/var/lib/postgresql/data --name pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PASSWORD} --rm -p 5432:5432 postgres`
    ];

    return runCmd(cmd);
}
```

add execution bit to this ts file and run it in terminal:

[image: error message]

after this, I tried

```
function runPg() {
    const cmd = [
        "docker", 
        "run",
        `-d -v ${VOLUME}:/var/lib/postgresql/data --name pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PASSWORD} --rm -p 5432:5432 postgres`
    ];

    return runCmd(cmd);
}
```

move out subcommand `run` from command options.

I got this:
[image: error message]

I guess that `Deno.run` doesn't simply concatenate the passed-in string of command particles, but I cannot find enough information on this subject in order to fix the issue.

I haven't gone through the rust source code on this API, but I thought it's better to ask for help before trying the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify each part of the command as a separate string in the `cmd` array:

```
function runPg() {
    const cmd = [
        "docker", 
        "run",
        "-d",
        "-v",
        `${VOLUME}:/var/lib/postgresql/data`,
        "--name",
        "pg",
        "-e",
        `POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}`,
        "--rm",
        "-p",
        "5432:5432",
        "postgres"
    ];

    return runCmd(cmd);
}
```

This will send `run` as the first argument to `docker` instead of sending `run -d …` as the first argument.

You can also build your command as a single string and then use `split(" ")` as long as no arguments contain spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works.
Could you, if possible, elaborate on the underlying mechanism about how arguments are passed down to the OS? or Shell? 

Say, how is `["echo", "1", "2"]` different from `["echo", "1 2"]` under this context.

Comment: I've seen this with other languages too. `["echo", "1", "2"]` is `echo 1 2` while `["echo", "1 2"]` is `echo 1\ 2`. The first sends two arguments to `echo` while the second sends only one. As such, `docker run -d\ -v…` sends only two arguments to `docker` (and therefore only one argument to `docker run`) whereas splitting it up sends many arguments. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

a follow up on my trial-n-error journey on this top.

While reading a book about unix shell programming, it points out a way to help the shell differentiate the **space in identifier** and the **space as delimiter**. When one tries to `cat` a file named `a b` (there is a space in between), the command should be `cat a\ b` or, using quotes, `cat 'a b'`.

This gives me an idea why my command does not work in Deno. See, each item in the `cmd` string list is an **identifier**, when I mix up **delimiter-space** with identifiers, the command is interpreted in the wrong way.

For example.

If I'd like to `cat` a file named `a b`. In Deno.run, I need to use `{ cmd: ["cat", "a b"] }`.

If I'd like to `cat` two files named `a` and `b`. In Deno.run, I need to use `{ cmd: ["cat", "a", "b"] }`.

Just remember that space in a command particle counts as a part of that term.